# jQuery DataTables - Refactoring Code to remove 'aoColumn' duplication

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using jQuery DataTables to render a timeline and each column represents a day. I have a method that is called when each column (day) is rendered and it's passed in a date from an array.

Is there a better way to write the code below so that i'm not repeating myself 7 times whilst still being able to pass in the array item? I cannot see anything that stands out in the docs.

```
dataTable = $('#example').dataTable({
"bRetrieve":true,
"bProcessing":true,
"aaData": data,
// DataTables requires a render function for each column (day)
"aoColumns":[
    {
        "mData":null,
        "fnRender":function (obj) {
            return day(obj, week[0]);
        }
    },
    {
        "mData":null,
        "fnRender":function (obj) {
            return day(obj, week[1]);
        }
    },
    {
        "mData":null,
        "fnRender":function (obj) {
            return day(obj, week[2]);
        }
    },
    {
        "mData":null,
        "fnRender":function (obj) {
            return day(obj, week[3]);
        }
    },
    {
        "mData":null,
        "fnRender":function (obj) {
            return day(obj, week[4]);
        }
    },
    {
        "mData":null,
        "fnRender":function (obj) {
            return day(obj, week[5]);
        }
    },
    {
        "mData":null,
        "fnRender":function (obj) {
            return day(obj, week[6]);
        }
    }
]
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution, using [$.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/):

```
dataTable = $("#example").dataTable({
    bRetrieve: true,
    bProcessing: true,
    aaData: data,
    aoColumns: $.map(Array(7), function(value, index) {
        return {
            mData: null,
            fnRender: function(obj) {
                return day(obj, week[index]);
            }
        };
    })
});
```

In the code above, `Array(7)` creates a sparse array of seven elements (indexed `0` to `6`), all set to `undefined`. Then, `$.map()` projects object literals from the indices in that array. The result is an array of object literals with the second argument to `day()` varying with the current index.

Comment: Fantastic, Thank you! I should have thought of that. One thing I didn't mention is before these dynamic columns is a normal column that does not call a method or have a fnRender property. Shall I just increase the array by one and check for 0 index? or can I just add that before the map?

Comment: @user, the [concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) method can help you there. You can write something like `aoColumns: [yourFirstColumn].concat($.map(...))`. You might have to specify `day(obj, week[index + 1])` in that case, depending on how your indexing works.